# Remove a row based on conditional value of other rows in multiple columns in r

Tags: r

I am trying to remove a row on the condition that it does not have a specific value in another row based on the same column. (if a CASEID does not have a correlating form 8, delete the CASEID)
e.g.

```
Form  CASEID  
7        001  
8        001  
8        001  
7        002  
7        003  
8        003  
8        003
```

I have tried to search for an answer to this and haven't been able to find one. I feel like I need an if statement but my co-worker suggested a subset function. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the expected output.  What is the specific value?  Try `subset(df1, Form != 8)`

Comment: Maybe you want (with `dplyr`) `group_by(your_data, CASEID) %>% filter(any(Form == 8))`? This will remove CASEIDs that don't have any rows with `Form = 8`. As akrun says, it's hard to understand if this is what you want or not. Desired output for your sample input and a clearer explanation would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions that I could think of. One using subset and the other with dplyr's `inner_join()`.

The difference between the solutions is that in option 1, duplicate rows and the original order has been retained, and in option 2 duplicate rows have been removed.

**Solution 1 - using subset and keeping duplicate rows:**

```
df[df$CASEID %in% subset(df, Form == 8)$CASEID, ]
```

The result is:

```
  Form CASEID
1    7      1
2    8      1
3    8      1
5    7      3
6    8      3
7    8      3
```

**Solution 2 - with inner_join()**

```
library(dplyr)
subset(df, Form == 8) %>% 
      select(CASEID) %>% 
      inner_join(df) %>% 
      select(Form, CASEID) %>% 
      distinct()
```

The result is:

```
  Form CASEID
1    7      1
2    8      1
3    7      3
4    8      3
```

Comment: Thank you! solution 1 worked perfectly. Apparently I was over thinking it, but good to have this question out there for anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: Glad it worked. Would be good if you upvoted the answer as well :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df <- subset(df, Form==8)
```

The second parameter of the `subset` function is a logical expression, just like an *if* statement, as you mentioned. Here, we subset rows based on if their form column is equal to 8.